# Modify appearance of Part Title in the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, color, memoir, parts

I want to divide my thesis into two `parts`: a background part and the thesis part. In the table of contents, I want the formatting of the parts to differ from the rest: I want the parts to be bigger, both the `Part` itself and the name of the part, and to be `PineGreen` in color.

I have almost done this successfully, but the part titles are not affected by my codes. See the MWE. Does someone know how to get this correct?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\scshape\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\scshape\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{\scshape\color{PineGreen}\Large Part }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Background}
    \chapter{The problem with manganese}
    \chapter{The risk assessment}


\part{Thesis}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? When I compile the example, `Part I` and `Part II` in the toc are green, as are the two part title pages.

Comment: Then the OP is doing it all wrong, `\cftpartname` should not really contain font settings, use `\cftpartfont`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is correct to use `\cftpartname` to add "Part" before the names.

But one should use `\cftpartfont` to control font settings for the part lines in the table of contents. (These are described in the `memoir` manual, `texdoc memoir`, p. 151.)

It is also possible, if desired, to use `\cftpartpagefont` to apply the same color to the page number for each part.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}

\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\scshape\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\HUGE\scshape\color{PineGreen}}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartfont}{\scshape\color{PineGreen}\Large}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Part\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpagefont}{\color{PineGreen}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{Background}
    \chapter{The problem with manganese}
    \chapter{The risk assessment}


\part{Thesis}
    \chapter{Introduction}
    \chapter{Conclusion}

\end{document}
```

It would be better to put the color in a macro so it can be redefined more easily.

[image]